# App Engine Django Form Uniqueness Validation?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-forms

Is there a simpler way to use uniqueness validation with Django Forms in AppEngine?

I understand that performance would be problem if we keep an uniqueness constraint but since the amount of data being added is very small performance is not a big concern, rather development time is a concern here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keys for uniqueness:

> The complete key of an entity,
> including the path, the kind and the
> name or numeric ID, is unique and
> specific to that entity. The complete
> key is assigned when the entity is
> created in the datastore, and none of
> its parts can change...
>
> Every entity has an identifier. An
> application can assign its own
> identifier for use in the key by
> giving the instance constructor a
> key_name argument (a str value):

```
s = Story(key_name="xzy123")
```

> ...Once the entity has been created, its
> ID or name cannot be changed.

**EDIT**

As jbochi noted, this could be dangerous and you could loss data. Another way to achieve the same is using an hash function with shard counters. A good example is showed in ["Paging through large datasets"](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/paging.html) article.

Comment: Beware that the old instance will be overwritten if you try to save a new one with the same `key_name`. No errors will be raised.